# "Your APK needs to have the package name X" error

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I'm getting this error from Google play when I'm trying to upload new APK for an existing project.

Here is the error:

> Your APK needs to have the package name com.nsetrading.app.
>   Upload failed

Here is my manifest:

```
package="com.nsetrading.app"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.3"
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using Gradle? If so, please post your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I have made anther APK file with the same content with out any changes and tried to uploaded it after 24 hours from the first time and its surprisingly working..